# GWT JSNI return a js-function

Tags: javascript, gwt, d3.js

How can I return a JavaScript *function* from JSNI in GWT? I tried it the following way:

```
/* JSNI method returning a js-function */
public static native JavaScriptObject native_getFunction() /*-{
    return function(a,b){
        //do some stuff with a,b
    }
}-*/;
```

Store the function in a variable

```
/* outside from GWT: store the function in a variable */
JavaScriptObject myFunction = native_getFunction();
```

Using the function afterwards produces the following error message:

```
(TypeError): object is not a function
```

Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to do that???

Comment: The returned function is a d3.js transformation function which is used in several other JSNI methods to transform some data. To avoid redundancy and to dynamically change the transformation I would like to store it in a variable.

Comment: I don't understand why you cannot simply call this JS function from other JSNI methods, like you call any JS in your document, without storing it in a variable.

Comment: (1) why not call the function directly: as I said it is a transformation function from d3.js, but with custom parameters written by me. So whenever I would need the transformation function in any JSNI method I would have to write again the transformation function (duplicate code, maintainablility).
(2) Therefore I define the function only once, store it in a variable and can then give this function as a parameter to any JSNI method which needs the transformation.

Comment: You can define your JS function, inject it in the document (using GWT ScriptInjector), and call it directly from any JSNI method. But I like Simon-Pierre's solution.

Comment: Thanks very much. It's also a really nice solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me. Declare these methods:

```
public static native JavaScriptObject native_getFunction() /*-{
    return function(a,b){
        //do some stuff with a,b
    }
}-*/;

private native void invoke(JavaScriptObject func)/*-{
    func("a", "b");
}-*/;
```

And then, you use these methods this way:

```
JavaScriptObject func = native_getFunction();
invoke(func);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider you `appName.nochache.js(GWT)`   in  `Homepage.html`

in `homepage.html`

```
<script>
    function printMyName(name) {
        alert("Hello from JavaScript, " + name);
    }
    </script>
```

In your Gwt :

Within your Gwt source, you can access the sayHello() JS function through JSNI:

```
native void printMyNameInGwt(String name) /*-{
  $wnd.printMyName(name); // $wnd is a JSNI synonym for 'window'
}-*/;
```

you can assign them to variables also

```
native void printMyNameInGwt(String name) /*-{
  var myname =$wnd.printMyName(name); // return that for your purposes
}-*/;
```

Note : if you are calling an js methods of any exterenal file that should be append on your html page with `<script>`  tags...

Comment: I think extracting the relevant methods to the html page would also be a nice solution. Thanks.