# How to use History.js with GWT?

Tags: gwt, browser-history, history.js, gwt-history, html5-history

I want to use [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) from Google Web Toolkit.

I know GWT has History functionality of it's own, but I don't like it because it uses the hashes in the URI, I want to use the new HTML5 History API as much as possible.

The only current way that I can think of to run History.js and GWT together is to write the History.js part in plain Javascript (or jQuery) and then manually call a GWT method.

It would be nice if it was possible to use the whole History.js functionality from within GWT's Java files.

Comment: is existing GWT History functionality any issue? why did you not like it? can you please brief it. What will you do any advance by using History.js?

Comment: I added the reason. History.js uses the new HTML5 History API when possible, GWT always uses hashes in the URL, which I want to avoid.

Comment: ok. You can do using jsni: refer https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pain at all with that .

You just simple add your History js file on your document and you can use it .

Here i answered how you can use an external js in GWT .

[Using externel js in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14712014/gwt-jsni-return-a-js-function/14714901#14714901)

After you call the native method you can continue with gwt method

Comment: I don't fully understand JSNI by reading about it, but I will test it, thanks!

Comment: That's great ,without JSNI you can't communicate further from GWT to Native JS.